# malloc: *** error for object 0x14d3e300: double free CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have this function to fetch data to CoreData. 
This information is used to update a UITableView.

```
- (NSArray*)haveNewContentsInCategory{
    NSArray *aux = [self fetchAllReceiptCategorys];
    NSMutableArray *hiddens=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (ReceiptCategory *rec in aux) {
        NSEntityDescription *entDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Content" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [request setEntity:entDesc];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoryId == %@",rec.catId];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        BOOL hidden=NO;
        for (Content *cont in results) {
            if ([cont.newContent boolValue]) {
                hidden=YES;
            }
        }
        [hiddens addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:hidden]];
    }
    return hiddens;
}
```

View Controller

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    categorys = [[CoreDataManager instance] fetchAllReceiptCategorys];
    hiddens = [[CoreDataManager instance] haveNewContentsInCategory];
    [_tvTable reloadData];
}
```

The first time you press the view everything works fine. but when I go to this view a second time this error happens.

> malloc: *** error for object 0x14d3e300: double free
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: So have you set a breakpoint to see the exact line it crashes?